# sudo visudo in a Dockerfile with CentOS base image

Tags: centos, docker, sudo, sudoers, dockerfile

I am creating a `Dockerfile` using the `centos:7` base image. I need to edit the file at `etc/sudoers` and append `NOPASSWD` privileges to it for a new user and some groups.

I have looked up in forums that its better to use `sudo visudo` while editing the `sudoers` file instead of using `cat`? However, I am an absolute beginner and any pointers regarding how that can be written in a `Dockerfile` would be appreciated.